# How do you increase the spacing on text within LibGDX labels

Tags: android, libgdx

So I'm following along with some tutorials for creating an application with LibGDX, and when I go to print parts of the UI to the screen, the text is all bunched up. How do I increase the spacing, or is it due to something else I've done?

[image]

```
....
    game = gam;
    stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(800, 400));
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    uiSkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"), new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.atlas")));
    Label nameLabel = new Label("Name:", uiSkin);
    TextField nameText = new TextField("", uiSkin);
    Label addressLabel = new Label("Address:", uiSkin);
    TextField addressText = new TextField("", uiSkin);

    table = new Table();
    table.add(nameLabel).expandX();
    table.add(nameText).width(200);
    table.row();
    table.add(addressLabel);
    table.add(addressText).width(200);
    table.setFillParent(true);
    stage.addActor(table);
    table.setDebug(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, feeling silly now. It was due to the fact that I set such an odd aspect ratio when I initialised my Stage. I passed in half the width and height of the phone screen instead, and it comes up a lot neater.

Comment: Your viewport size ratio should match the one of the device screen :)

Comment: I haven't been able to mark my own answer as accepted cause I don't have enough points to do so until after 2 days, but the problem has been solved

Comment: All right :) Don't forget to come back and accept it!

Answer (score 0):

For later questions, to answer them directly - there are parameters in fonts that are responsible for line height and it's spacing in LibGDX.

You can find it in your `.fnt` file and `BitmapFontData`.

**.fnt file:**

[image]

**BitmapFontData**:

[image]

Comment: Spacing seems to be totally ignored. I tried setting it to 2000 even and it didn't change at all.